# Extracting text within <b> tag and <div> separately using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="quote">
    <b>Head 1</b> Text 1
</div>
<div class="quote">
    <b>Head 2</b> Text 2
    <br/> <b>Head 3</b> Text 3
</div>
```

I need to extract head 1 head 2 head 3 separately and text 1 text 2 text 3 separately.
I tried doing it this way , but only head 1 , head 2 is getting extracted with the entire text(including head 1 ,head 2) of the div class. 
**PS the number of nested b tags might vary with different div class. I need to iterate over all the div class='quote' in the page**

```
def parser(url):
    page_content=BeautifulSoup(url.content,'html.parser')
    df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Dialogues','Character'])
    for item in page_content.findAll('div',{'class':'quote'}):
            character= item.find('b').text[:-1]
            quotes=item.text
            df=df.append({'Dialogues':quotes,'Character': character},ignore_index=True)

    return df
```

**EDIT I need the data in two separate columns of df in such format.**

```
Character   Quote
Head 1  Text 1
Head 2  Text 2
Head 3  Text 3
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
targets = page_content.select('div.quote')
for target in targets:
    for s in target.stripped_strings:
        print(s)
```

Output:

```
Head 1
Text 1
Head 2
Text 2
Head 3
Text 3
```

Edit:

To add to a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
heads = []
tails = []
targets = page_content.select('div.quote')
for target in targets:
    data = target.stripped_strings
    mu = list(data)
    for i in range(0,len(mu),2):
        heads.append(mu[i])
        tails.append(mu[i+1])

items = list(zip(heads,tails))
pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Character','Quote'])
```

Output:

```
    Character   Quote
0   Head 1  Text 1
1   Head 2  Text 2
2   Head 3  Text 3
```

Comment: hi @JackFleeting , i was able to extract using the above method, but is there a way i can get them separately so that i can append them according into two separate columns

Comment: @nerd_cs - They are already separated. Edit your question to show exactly how you want your "two separate columns" to look like.